# Check List<T> for duplications with optional words to exclude

Tags: c#

I have a method as below. Method return either false/true either when list contains duplicates or not. I would like to extend my method to say for instance (optional) that i want to exclude specific items from check. For instance i want to check entire list as it is now or i want to say for instance exclude: string.empty items or for instance string.empty and "some word". Is it possible?

```
public static bool IsListContainsDuplicates<T>(List<T> list)
{
    return list.GroupBy(n => n).Any(c => c.Count() > 1);
}
```

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: So when `"some word"` is contained twice in your list, it should be returned as duplicate? Apart from this: why is your method generic when it actually works on list of strings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public static bool ContainsDuplicates<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, IEnumerable<T> itemsToExclude = null)
{
    if (itemsToExclude == null) itemsToExclude = Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    return items.Except(itemsToExclude)
                .GroupBy(n => n)
                .Any(c => c.Count() > 1);
}
```

But i'd prefer this implementation because it's more performant:

```
public static bool ContainsDuplicates<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, IEnumerable<T> itemsToExclude = null)
{
    if (itemsToExclude == null) itemsToExclude = Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    HashSet<T> set = new HashSet<T>();
    return !items.Except(itemsToExclude).All(set.Add);
}
```

Comment: Questions: 1) Does it work also with arrays besides list<T>? 2) If i want to exclude empty i should pass just as "" ?

Comment: Yes, it works with every type that implements `IEnumerable<T>`, so also with lists or arrays. If `T` is a custom type you either need to override `Equals`+`GetHashCode` or provide a `IEqualityComparer<T>` for `ContainsDuplicates`(that overload is missing yet).

Comment: Great. Is it just to put this keyword before both arguments to make it extension method just enough Tim?

Comment: @DinoDin2: the method must be static, `this` must be before the first argument and the method must be in a static class(the extension-class).

Comment: mean i can modify your method this item: -> (this IEnumerable<T> items <-  then to use it like this e.g: 
            var inList = new[] { "a", "b", string.Empty, "d" };
            var exclude = new[] { string.Empty, "b"};
            var cacsascascascasc = inList.ContainsDuplicates(exclude);

Comment: @DinoDin2: why you don't try? Yes, that's the way

Comment: @DinoDin2: i have provided another, more efficient, approach.

Comment: it works. If possible can you also show third example to your answer: To return bool either all items in list has values but if at least one empty string or "some string" (could be many specific words) it should return false. Thanks in advance i marked this grwat answer as answer ! P.S If items count is 0 also return false

Comment: @DinoDin2: maybe you should ask another question if you have more questions. But it's not clear why you are talking of strings if the extension method handles any type. You should create another extension method for this case that only handles strings.

Comment: here's new topic wish you to answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52514887/check-ienumerablet-is-filled-with-optional-words-not-to-count

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Except()`. From MSDN:

> Produces the set difference of two sequences by using the default
>   equality comparer to compare values.

```
return list.Except(listToExclude).GroupBy(n => n).Any(c => c.Count() > 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of making your method more complicated, you should open it more to combine it with others:

```
public static class MyLinqMethods
{
  public static bool HasDuplicates<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence)
  {
      return sequence.GroupBy(n => n).Any(c => c.Count() > 1);
  }
}
```

Now you can use it with Linq:

```
var original = new[] { string.Empty, "Hello", "World", string.Empty };

var duplicatesInOriginal = original.HasDuplicates();

var duplicatesIfStringEmptyIsIgnored = original.Where(o => o != string.Empty).HasDuplicates();
```

Comment: Can i exclude more items but passing them to method itself?

Comment: Yes, if you want to use the `this` keyword to make it an extension method, then it has to be in a `static class`.

Answer (score 1):

This will also help, using a 'params' in arguments and then doing Except()

```
  public static bool IsListContainsDuplicates<T>(List<T> list, params T[] optional)
        {
            return list.Except(optional).GroupBy(n => n).Any(c => c.Count() > 1);
        }
```

You can call like this if you doesn't want to exclude anything:

```
IsListContainsDuplicates(list)
```

Else, just pass the params values, for example, if the list is an integer list then,

```
IsListContainsDuplicates(list,5,4)
```