# Check IEnumerable<T> is filled with optional words not to count

Tags: c#

I am trying to create extension isEmpty method which would check whether my IEnumerable contains at least one element. Returning either true/false.
I would like to also be able to exclude some specific items from check therefore it should be like this:

**1st check:** if `list` items count == 0 then return true

**2nd check:** If not `list` empty (count > 0) then check what elements are there. If i say for instance in parameter `listSpecialItems` that i want: string.empty, "whatever", "dd" then if `list` contains only those items it should still return true. Means `listSpecialItems` defines items as they would not exist (not counts).

This is so far what i did, however at the moment it only checks items count.

```
public static bool IsEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, IEnumerable<T> listSpecialItems)
{
     if (list is ICollection<T>) return ((ICollection<T>)list).Count == 0;
         return !list.Any();
}
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] with at least six different sample inputs **and the expected results for each of those inputs**.

Comment: Didn´t you ask a very similar question before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52513087/check-listt-for-duplications-with-optional-words-to-exclude?

Comment: @HimBromBeere yes, according to Tim i make ne topic.

Comment: `return !list.Any(item => !listSpecialItems.Any(special => special == item));`: `list` in **not** empty it there's `item` in the `list` such that it doesn't equal to `Any` `special` item

Comment: @DinoDin2 Then make clear what is different from the other question. I have a hard time understanding your question and even more what makes this question different than the previous one.

Comment: Well, the question is not really a duplicate, but it´s very similar. Both questions have in common that there is some "except-the-following-elements"-condition.

Comment: Tim suggested to create a new topic if your actual intent is really only suitable for strings. However both question don´t have *any* constraint on `T` and thus should work for any type. This current question still has the generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.All` and `Contains`, no need for `Count` or cast:

```
public static bool IsEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, IEnumerable<T> treatAsEmpty = null)
{
    if (treatAsEmpty == null) treatAsEmpty = Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    return list.All(treatAsEmpty.Contains);
}
```

this handles these edge cases correctly:

- an empty list: returns `true`
- an empty `treatAsEmpty`: returns `false` if the list isn't empty